# Select text in IE 10 'modern'

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

Does anyone know if there is a way to select text for copying and pasting in IE 10, when running in 'Modern' UI mode?

I should qualify, when using a device that only has a touch interface, such as a tablet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a tablet for this answer, and all I have to do to select text is to tap a word and two circles appear beneath the word. Drag these to select more words, then press and hold the selection and a popup menu should appear with a copy command in it.